# slicing pandas dataframe with an array of indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this..

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4,4,5,6,7,12,13], 'B' : 
     [1,2,3,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,]})

df

    A   B
0   5   1
1   6   2
2   3   3
3   4   5
4   4   5
5   5   6
6   6   7  
7   7   8
8  12   9
9  13  10
```

and I have an array of indices

```
array = np.array([0,1,2,4,7,8])
```

Now I can subset the dataframe with the array indices like this

```
df.iloc[array]
```

Which gives me a dataframe with indices present in the array.

```
    A  B
0   5  1
1   6  2
2   3  3
4   4  5
7   7  8
8  12  9
```

Now I want all the rows which are not present in the array index, row index which i want is `[3,5,6,9]` 
I am trying to do something like this but it gives me an error.

`df.iloc[~loc]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with inverting a boolean `Series` by `~`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4,4,5,6,7,12,13], 'B' : 
     [1,2,3,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,]})

print df
    A   B
0   5   1
1   6   2
2   3   3
3   4   5
4   4   5
5   5   6
6   6   7
7   7   8
8  12   9
9  13  10

array = np.array([0,1,2,4,7,8])
print array
[0 1 2 4 7 8]

print df.index.isin(array)
[ True  True  True False  True False False  True  True False]

print ~df.index.isin(array)
[False False False  True False  True  True False False  True]

print df[ ~df.index.isin(array)]
    A   B
3   4   5
5   5   6
6   6   7
9  13  10
```

Answer (score 2):

Use sets:

```
In [7]: wanted = [0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8]

In [8]: not_wanted = set(df.index) - set(wanted)

In [9]: not_wanted
Out[9]: {3, 5, 6, 9}

In [11]: not_wanted = list(not_wanted)

In [12]: not_wanted
Out[12]: [9, 3, 5, 6]

In [13]: df.iloc[not_wanted]
Out[13]: 
    A   B
9  13  10
3   4   5
5   5   6
6   6   7
```

Comment: I have an array index not a list. When I use your code it gives me an error.    `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`

Comment: In the prompt `[7]`, I set it up as a list, but you can also cast the array index as a list. Use `list(array_index)` for this purpose.

Comment: You may wish to cast the entire `array_index` into a set in one line by going: `set(list(array_index))`. From that point, the set operations are the quickest way to get to the complement of the set of indices that you don't want.

Comment: ok. It worked. But why its not working if I have an array like this `(array([ 2,  3, 4], dtype=int64))`

Comment: That is because a tuple is also not hashable.